# How can I resize icons in Ubuntu 20.04 app drawer?

Tags: gnome-shell

This is the normal size of the icons in app drawer:

[image: icon size with dock at left]

Then I decided to move the dock at the bottom of the screen, and the icon size decreased like this:

[image: icon size with dock at the bottom]

Now, my question is how can I have bigger icons in app drawer even when my dock is at bottom of the screen ?

I noticed another glitch. If I open a folder within app drawer, I get huge icons both inside & outside of the folder. Upon closing they revert back to their small size.

[image: Icon size changes while opening a folder]

Solutions tried;

1. With the **gnome extension** [More columns in applications view](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1305/more-columns-in-applications-view/), I was able to change the grid size of app drawer but I didn't find any suitable extension for icon size so far.
2. In **dconf-editor** at */org/gnome/shell/extensions/desktop-icons* I found one option to change desktop icon size but no customization option was there for app drawer icons.

Comment: Hey Mridul Gain! What is the GNOME version which you're using?

Comment: The default one shipped with Ubuntu 20.04.1 i.e GNOME Shell 3.36.4

Comment: Nothing you can do probably without editing source code or at least style sheets. The icons scale in a fixed grid to the available space. This probably will be fixed in the current Gnome Shell, where the number of icons and rows is adapted as to fill the free space.

Comment: I just observed this issue in my arch system. There is no way around the issue as of now.